# why do we need parentheses for destructor definition?

Tags: c++, parameters, destructor

I know how to define destructor is just like this

```
~ClassName()
{

}
```

and destructor can't have parameter. then why we must write parentheses after the class name? since destructor can't have parameter and i think there is no benefit of it. or there is other function of it?

i think it will be better if there is no parantheses needed because it make clear destructor can't have parameter

```
~ClassName
{

}
```

Comment: destructor is a special function, which is a function

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a good forum for asking about why a design decision was made 30 years ago or commenting that you don't care for it.

Comment: C++ already has the notion that a callable doesn't accept parameters, it's an empty parameter list. Why on earth would breaking consistency with the rest of the grammar be a good idea!?

Comment: Also, please visit the [help], in particular note what types of questions you [should ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and which you [shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two reasons so far

> - It is a function so it needs the syntax declaration of a function.
> - Why is the function declaration syntax like that? It's how the grammar
>     was defined.

Answer (score -2):

In the D programming language the parenthesis of functions are optional when there are no arguments. D is designed to be a better C++. You might be interested in that language https://dlang.org/